# Counting number of joined rows in left join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count, left-join

I'm trying to write an aggregate query in SQL which returns the count of all records joined to a given record in a table; If no records were joined to the given record, then the result for that record should be `0`:

### Data

My database looks like this (I'm not able to change the structure, unfortunately):

```
MESSAGE
----------------------------------------------
MESSAGEID   SENDER        SUBJECT
----------------------------------------------
1           Tim           Rabbit of Caerbannog
2           Bridgekeeper  Bridge of Death

MESSAGEPART
----------------------------------------------
MESSAGEID   PARTNO        CONTENT
----------------------------------------------
1           0             (BLOB)
1           1             (BLOB)
3           0             (BLOB)
```

(`MESSAGEPART` has a composite `PRIMARY KEY("MESSAGEID", "PARTNO")`)

### Desired output

Given the data above I should get something like this:

```
MESSAGEID   COUNT(*)
-----------------------------------------------
1           2
2           0
```

It seems obvious that I need to do a left join on the `MESSAGE` table, but how do I return a count of `0` for rows where the joined columns from `MESSAGEPART` are `NULL`? I've tried the following:

### Logic

I've tried

```
SELECT m.MESSAGEID, COUNT(*) FROM MESSAGE m
LEFT JOIN MESSAGEPART mp ON mp.MESSAGEID = m.MESSAGEID
GROUP BY m.MESSAGEID;
```

However, this returns

```
MESSAGEID   COUNT(*)
-----------------------------------------------
1           2
2           1
```

I've also tried

```
SELECT mp.MESSAGEID, COUNT(*) FROM MESSAGE m
LEFT JOIN MESSAGEPART mp ON mp.MESSAGEID = m.MESSAGEID
GROUP BY mp.MESSAGEID;
```

but this returns

```
MESSAGEID   COUNT(*)
-----------------------------------------------
1           2
            1
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: For a start, use `m.MESSAGEID` (will always be there) rather than `mp.MESSAGEID` (will only be there when there's a match).

Answer (score 115, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
SELECT m.MESSAGEID, sum((case when mp.messageid is not null then 1 else 0 end)) FROM MESSAGE m
LEFT JOIN MESSAGEPART mp ON mp.MESSAGEID = m.MESSAGEID
GROUP BY m.MESSAGEID;
```

The COUNT() function will count every row, even if it has null.  Using SUM() and CASE, you can count only non-null values.

EDIT: A simpler version taken from the top comment:

```
SELECT m.MESSAGEID, COUNT(mp.MESSAGEID) FROM MESSAGE m
LEFT JOIN MESSAGEPART mp ON mp.MESSAGEID = m.MESSAGEID
GROUP BY m.MESSAGEID;
```

Comment: It can be simplified a little. `sum(case....end)` can be replaced with simple `count(mp.messageid)`.  `Count(*)` counts, well, everything, including nulls and `count(col_name)` counts only non-null values.

Comment: Thanks @NicholasKrasnov.  I totally forgot that distinction.  The older I get, the more I forget.... sigh.... :-)

Comment: This was useful. I needed to see some other fields beside the one linking key. I found you can do that by adding the fields to both the select list and the group by clause.

Comment: After having tried tens of answers to other similar questions, this is one finally worked for me. It is the GROUP BY that I hadn't included earlier that makes this work, without having to use subqueries (you want to avoid that).

**Note:** if you want to add a WHERE clause it'll need to look like this:
`WHERE (mp.PARTNO = 1 OR mp.PARTNO IS NULL)` and is added before the `GROUP BY`

Comment: but what if you dont want to group by :(

Answer (score 22):

You *first* want to count in your messaepart table before joining, i think. Try this:

```
   SELECT m.MessageId
        , COALESCE(c, 0) as myCount
     FROM MESSAGE m
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MESSAGEID
                , count(*) c 
             FROM MESSAGEPART 
            GROUP BY MESSAGEID) mp
       ON mp.MESSAGEID = m.MESSAGEID
```

Comment: This is more complicated than the solution above, but I have to embed this query in another one anyway, so your solution was also ultimately helpful; cheers

Comment: however inefficient this may or may not be but for purposes of knowledge, it is extremely useful especially right now!

Answer (score 9):

Don't forget to use **DISTINCT** in case you will LEFT JOIN more than one table:

```
SELECT m.MESSAGEID, COUNT(DISTINCT mp.MESSAGEID) FROM MESSAGE m
LEFT JOIN MESSAGEPART mp ON mp.MESSAGEID = m.MESSAGEID
GROUP BY m.MESSAGEID;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Return one number as a total of the matching elements between two tables, based on matching columns**

In my case, I needed one total number returned for the number/count of matching items from a particular column and from two different tables.

For example, I have two separate tables that each have a PhoneNumber column. Between those two tables, I want to know how many from that column match.

Reference: https://www.guru99.com/joins.html

Using the same tables name above, it would look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT m.MESSAGEID) AS COUNT FROM MESSAGE m, MESSAGEPART mp
where mp.MESSAGEID = m.MESSAGEID;
```