# Embedding aggregate query in non-aggregate query

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count, subquery

I'm trying to create a database view which has the result of an aggregate query for a column value (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20120049/1391325) for the aggregate query used), e.g. something like

```
MESSAGEVIEW
----------------------------------------------
MESSAGEID    SENDER       PARTCOUNT        
----------------------------------------------
1            Tim          2
2            Bridgekeeper 0
```

I've tried this code for selecting the view data:

```sql
SELECT m.MESSAGEID, m.SENDER,
    (SELECT COUNT(mp.MESSAGEID)
         FROM MESSAGE m LEFT JOIN MESSAGEPART mp
         ON mp.MESSAGEID = m.MESSAGEID GROUP BY m.MESSAGEID) AS PARTCOUNT
    FROM MESSAGE m;
```

which returns `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`.

I've also tried

```sql
SELECT m.MESSAGEID, m.SENDER, COUNT(mp.MESSAGEID) AS PARTCOUNT
FROM MESSAGE m
LEFT JOIN MESSAGEPART mp ON mp.MESSAGEID = m.MESSAGEID 
GROUP BY m.MESSAGEID;
```

Which returns `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`.

How can I get a view which properly shows this information?

Comment: General remark, "not a GROUP BY expression." is probably Oracle way of telling yuo that you should put all non-aggregate fields in your group by in your second query, so m.SENDER should be there too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
SELECT m.MESSAGEID, m.SENDER,
    (SELECT COUNT(mp.MESSAGEID)
         FROM MESSAGEPART mp
         WHERE mp.MESSAGEID = m.MESSAGEID) AS PARTCOUNT
    FROM MESSAGE m;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a subquery (see @Jva answer) or with the following JOIN:

```
SELECT m.MESSAGEID, m.SENDER,
       mp.PartCount AS PARTCOUNT

       FROM MESSAGE m
           LEFT JOIN 
             (SELECT MESSAGEID,COUNT(*) as PartCount 
                     FROM MESSAGEPART GROUP BY MESSAGEID) as mp 
             ON m.MESSAGEID=mp.MESSAGEID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it into a single query without a subquery if you use count() in window function format:

```
SELECT m.MESSAGEID, m.SENDER, COUNT(mp.MESSAGEID) OVER (PARTITION BY m.MESSAGEID) AS PARTCOUNT
FROM MESSAGE m
LEFT JOIN MESSAGEPART mp ON mp.MESSAGEID = m.MESSAGEID;
```